# How do I seek using python in GCP Pubsub?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to use the Google Python pubsub client to seek to now in a subscription:

```
seek_request_dict =    {
        "subscription":subscription, 
        "time":current_time
        }
request = pubsub_v1.types.SeekRequest(seek_request_dict)
```

this gives the error:

```
TypeError: Message must be initialized with a dict: google.pubsub.v1.SeekRequest
```

I have tried:

```
request = pubsub_v1.SeekRequest(seek_request_dict)
```

but this gives:

```
AttributeError: module 'google.cloud.pubsub_v1' has no attribute 'SeekRequest'
```

So smart ones what do I need to do? TIA!

Comment: You are using packages from `google.cloud.pubsub_v1`, the second one works if you import `google.pubsub_v1` instead, seek is defined in both. Not quite sure what the idea is behind those 2 different packages. https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/pubsub/latest/google.cloud.pubsub_v1.subscriber.client.Client#google_cloud_pubsub_v1_subscriber_client_Client_seek